# Inverse of a regular expression (JavaScript/Titanium)

Tags: javascript, android, regex, titanium, inverse

I have the following code in Titanium to check if user input is non-numeric:

```
textBox.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    var patt = new RegExp('^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$','gi');
    if (e.value.match(patt) != null) {
        //insert action here
    }
});
```

I personally would like to delete non-decimal characters when a user tries to input one.  However, in order to do so, I would need to use `replace(inversePatt, "")`.  I would like to know, how do I get the inverse of my regular expression?

Comment: You mean the complement? Inverse of a reg-ex doesn't make much sense..

Comment: I guess so.  I would like to delete all non-numeric characters from my user input, as well as any extra decimal points after the first.

Comment: Take a look at this SO question about getting the complement of any regex.[How do I turn any regex into an complement of itself without complex hand editing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3977455/874257)

Comment: Could you just do `if(e.value.match(patt) == null)` then replace / remove unwanted characters?

Comment: Okay, I tried using your statement and did `textbox.value = textBox.value.slice(0, -1)`, however, now my app locks up on numeric input.  Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to delete non-decimal characters, you should be able to match every:

```
[^\.\d]
```

group returned.

([^.\d] should work - here a dot needn't be escaped)

The carat inverts inside brackets.
It basically means "not a dot or a number".

Check out:

http://www.scriptular.com

**EDIT:**
I think this has your answer:

[Restricting input to textbox: allowing only numbers and decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808184/restricting-input-to-textbox-allowing-only-numbers-and-decimal-point)

**EDIT 2**:
You could also use this:

```
var success = /^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/.test(input);
```

as per:

[Limiting input field to one decimal point and two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252628/limiting-input-field-to-one-decimal-point-and-two-decimal-places)

you can also demand a number before the decimal point like so:

```
var success = /^\d+\.?\d{0,2}$/.test(input); // uses + instead of *
```

Comment: I tested this on the string: 
"adsf3.344564564 56trrty ert"
Try to give examples of text you want to match.

Comment: However, I want to restrict the input to only one decimal point as well.  Your example lets me enter more than one decimal point.

Comment: you may not need to have an entire regex for the whole box. just check each new char as it comes in. See the link.

Comment: If I do that, how would I know if there is a second decimal point?  I would need to know if there is more than one decimal point, and I don't see how I would do that by checking each new character.

Comment: then obviously you're going to need to use a regex on it to see if there already is one. see my edit. maybe that will help.

Comment: Thanks.  Your solution worked and my app is no longer locking up.

Comment: Side note, you *don't* need to escape a dot in a character class. So `[^.\d]` is absolutely fine

Comment: i suspected so - but didn't want to cause confusion. thanks for making that clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle chars in a key event, something like below should work.
As an acceptance validation, use something like `\d` to make sure a digit is present.

```
 # ^(?:\.|\d*|\d+\.|\d*\.\d+)$
 # "^(?:\\.|\\d*|\\d+\\.|\\d*\\.\\d+)$"


 ^                       # BOL 
 (?:
      \.                 # dot, or 
   |  
      \d*                # optional digits (if no digits, matches ^$) 
   |  
      \d+ \.             # digits and dot
   |  
      \d* \. \d+         # optional digits and dot and digits
 )
 $                       # EOL
```